# Is it possible to wrap a SliverGrid(is a children of CustomScrollView) inside the OrientationBuilder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I am trying to update the number of items(crossAxisCount) and also the childAspectRatio inside a SliverGrid based on the orientation.

I have tried to wrap the SliverGrid with the OrientationBuilder which throws a RenderLayout error because inside a sliver the immediate child should be a RenderSliver!

SLiverGrid inside _gridview(): GridList.dart

```
import 'package:app_jokally/model/Items.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'ItemList.dart';

class GridList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridListState createState() => _GridListState();
}

class _GridListState extends State<GridList> {
  List<Items> itemList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    itemList = _itemList();
    return Container(
      child: _gridView(),
    );
  }

  Widget _gridView() {
    return SliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 0.86,
      ),
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) {
          return ItemList(context, items: itemList[index]);
        },
        childCount: itemList.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Items> _itemList() {
    return [
      Items(
        id: 0,
        shopName: "Demo",
        shopCategory: "General",
        street: "Lorem Ipsum 149",
        //houseNo:
        //zipCode:
        city: "Demo",
        province: "Demo",
        country: "Demo",
        rating: 4,
        imageUrl: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        bannerUrl: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        shopImg1: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        shopImg2: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        shopImg3: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        shopImg4: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
      ),
      Items(
        id: 1,
        shopName: "Demo",
        shopCategory: "General",
        street: "Lorem Ipsum 149",
        //houseNo:
        //zipCode:
        city: "Demo",
        province: "Demo",
        country: "Demo",
        rating: 4,
        imageUrl: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        bannerUrl: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        shopImg1: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        shopImg2: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        shopImg3: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
        shopImg4: 'assets/images/shop1.png',
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Parent CustomScrollView: ShopsList.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'GridList.dart';

class ShopList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _JkShopList createState() => _JkShopList();
}

class _JkShopList extends State<ShopList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: OrientationBuilder(
            builder: (context, orientation) {
              return CustomScrollView(
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverAppBar(
                    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                    floating: true,
                    titleSpacing: 0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 1.0,
                    title: _searchCard(),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: SizedBox(height: 15),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: _shopListTitle(),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: SizedBox(height: 15),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: ScrollableBadges(),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: SizedBox(height: 15),
                  ),
                  GridList(),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY

```
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building OrientationBuilder:
flutter: A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type
flutter: _RenderLayoutBuilder.
flutter: RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during
flutter: layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a
flutter: RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
flutter:
flutter: The RenderViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by:
flutter:   Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#fce57] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
flutter: RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#22327] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ←
flutter: _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#3c1e1] ← Scrollable ← PrimaryScrollController ← CustomScrollView ← ⋯
flutter:
flutter: The _RenderLayoutBuilder that did not match the expected child type was created by:
flutter:   LayoutBuilder ← OrientationBuilder ← Container ← GridList ← Viewport ←
flutter: IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#fce57] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
flutter: RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#22327] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ←
flutter: ⋯
flutter:
flutter:
```

Comment: This might be an article for you : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation

Comment: I think you want to wrap your entire customScrollView in the orientationBuilder not just the GridList

Comment: ok the second comment i can try that.

Comment: You're putting a non-Sliver widget where a sliver widget needs to go. That is, you're placing the orientationBuilder inside of the customScrollView as one of it's children.

Comment: Not only that, but(!), your GridList doesn't actually extend a Sliver of any kind and therefore wouldn't work as a SliverWidget either.

Comment: Take the GridList out of its own class and place it directly in the CustomScrollView's children list, also put the OrientationBuilder around the entire CustomScrollView and that should work.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments I gave I think this is what you're looking for:

```
class _JkShopList extends State<ShopList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: new OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation){
            return new CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  floating: true,
                  titleSpacing: 0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  elevation: 1.0,
                  title: _searchCard(),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SizedBox(height: 15),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: _shopListTitle(),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SizedBox(height: 15),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: ScrollableBadges(),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SizedBox(height: 15),
                ),
                new SliverGrid(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.86,
                  ),
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (context, index) {
                      return ItemList(context, items: itemList[index]);
                    },
                    childCount: itemList.length,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Adrian, I have updated my code! I need to access the items from GridList class.

Comment: I'd place those items in the _JkShopList class and access them there. You could also recreate a GridView class and put your list in that (I wouldn't do that), or the more appropriate option is to use some sort of state management package like ScopedModel or BLoC and separate your UI from your data/logic. The last option is the best option for these kinds of things, but would require some more work.